# How to delete local storage key on page refresh or page changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

i am trying to remove localstorage key on page refresh

i have tried

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
            localStorage.removeItem('selectedproduct');
        });
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Your implementation is correct. It will delete the key whenever a page is reloaded. However, on page change it won't, until or unless you have written the same code on the other page also.

Comment: Why not just use a variable for that? It will be gone on refresh/change without you having to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will allow you to remove an item before page refresh

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
    {
        localStorage.removeItem('selectedproduct');
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C standards, the correct ways is window.localStorage because the localStorage attribute is a part of window object. And it is not a function, it is an attribute.

Use with window global keyword:-

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('keyName');
```

Source: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you always writing `window.document`?